# Storing JSON objects in the postgreSQL using parameterized query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am having problems with saving JSON objects in the database using parameterized queries. I am using postman to send this object on red.body
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKRkP.png)

On my server side I havet his code:

```js
queryController.createQuery = (req, res, next) => {
  const { info }= req.body;
  const sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ($1) RETURNING *';
  db.query(sqlQuery, [info])
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result) res.locals.message = "Saved the query successfully";
    next();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return next({
      log: `queryController.createQuery: ERROR: ${typeof err === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(err) : err}`,
      message: { err: 'Error occurred in queryController.createQuery. Check server log for more details.'},
    })
  })
```

Why is that I still get this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnwuK.png)

```
throw new TypeError('Client was passed a null or undefined query')
      ^

TypeError: Client was passed a null or undefined query
```

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    info json NOT NULL
);
```

How do I format $1 correctly to get it accept it as JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Query example:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ($1) RETURNING *' USING '[{"size": "Small", "quantity": 1, "product_id": 1}]'::jsonb;
```